# Examine the behavior of $\mathit{e}^{x+yi}$ as $x\to \pm \infty$ and the behavior as $y\to \pm \infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Examine the behavior of $\mathit{e}^{x+yi}$ as $x\to \pm \infty$ and the behavior of $\mathit{e}^{x+yi}$ as $y\to \pm \infty$.

Here is my attempt:

As $x\to \infty$, then $\mathit{e}^{x+yi}=\mathit{e}^{x}(\cos y+i\sin y)\to \infty$ since $\mathit{e}^{x}\to\infty $ as $x\to \infty$.

As $x\to -\infty$, then $\mathit{e}^{x+yi}=\mathit{e}^{x}(\cos y+i\sin y)\to 0$ since $\mathit{e}^{x}\to0 $ as $x\to -\infty$.

As $y\to \infty$, then $\mathit{e}^{x+yi}=\mathit{e}^{x}(\cos y+i\sin y)$ diverges since $\sin y$ and $\cos y$ diverge as $y\to \infty$. Similarly when $y\to -\infty$.

Now these are just my guesses. What do you think? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The conclusions are right, but the justifications could be improved. For instance, why is $\cos(y) + i\sin(y) \neq 0$? If that were the case then $e^{x + yi} \rightarrow 0$. Another is $\sin(y), \cos(y)$ both diverge as $y \rightarrow \infty$, but two divergent sequences can sum to give a convergent sequence. It might help to realise $e^{x+iy} = e^x e^{iy}$ which is in polar form $re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: When you say $e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)\to \infty$, what exactly does that mean to you? I.e., what $\infty$ are you referring to? There are multiple ways to add infinities to the complex plane. By far the most common is the Riemann sphere, but the level of sophistication here makes me doubt that you've been introduced to that yet. So it is not helpful to just claim $e^{x+iy} \to \infty$ without having established a definite meaning for that expression.